# WiX running batch file, before file copy

Tags: installation, wix

I am Using WiX 3.5 for making installer, i need to copy many files and folder.
I used heat.exe to do that, and it is working fine.
But i need to call bat file during installation, and the bat file is present in those folders i mentioned above. That bat file is depended on some other files.
I am able to call the batch file but by that time the other files are not loaded.
Below is the custom action i am using for running bat file.

```
<Custom Action="InstallFeature" After="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[
    (&TypicalFeature=3) AND NOT(!TypicalFeature=3)
]]></Custom>
```

Need help, may be files are loading after i call the bat file.

Thanks
Ravi S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a batch file from an MSI is a *really really bad idea*. MSI is declarative - you simply define what the system should look like on a successful installation, if something goes wrong, MSI can roll back the changes.

However by using a batch file, Windows Installer doesn't know what changes were made to the system and can't roll anything back.

I would look into what the batch file is doing, and implement what it is doing either in WiX, or via a custom action in C++/C# with corresponding rollback action. (Native code is best, but it's hard. Managed code is the next best thing and VBScript is a last resort - but still better than a batch file)

Comment: Is there any way to create symbolic links through WIX?(mklink) @saschabeanumount

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, you'd need to call a custom action. I don't believe it's supported by MSI (and therefore Wix)